# Get better parse error message from ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

If I try to parse a broken XML the exception shows the line number. Is there a way to show the XML context?

I want to see the xml tags before and after the broken part.

Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring('<a><b></a>')
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp/foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    tree = ET.fromstring('<a><b></a>')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 1, column 8
```

Something like this would be nice:

```
ParseError:
<a><b></a>
=====^
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could make a helper function to do this:

```
import sys
import io
import itertools as IT
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
PY2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
StringIO = io.BytesIO if PY2 else io.StringIO

def myfromstring(content):
    try:
        tree = ET.fromstring(content)
    except ET.ParseError as err:
        lineno, column = err.position
        line = next(IT.islice(StringIO(content), lineno))
        caret = '{:=>{}}'.format('^', column)
        err.msg = '{}\n{}\n{}'.format(err, line, caret)
        raise 
    return tree

myfromstring('<a><b></a>')
```

yields

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 1, column 8
<a><b></a>
=======^
```

Comment: up-vote for using `err.position` didn't know about that.

Comment: @KobiK: I didn't know either, but a good introspection tool, like IPython, comes in handy to discover what's available in objects like `err`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works nice.

Comment: In Python 3, you wil lneed to replace `io.BytesIO` with `io.StringIO`

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best option but it's easy and simple, you can just parse the `ParseError`
Extract the line and column and then use it to show where is the problem.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ParseError
my_string = '<a><b><c></b></a>'
try:
    tree = ET.fromstring(my_string)
except ParseError as e:
    formatted_e = str(e)
    line = int(formatted_e[formatted_e.find("line ") + 5: formatted_e.find(",")])
    column = int(formatted_e[formatted_e.find("column ") + 7:])
    split_str = my_string.split("\n")
    print "{}\n{}^".format(split_str[line - 1], len(split_str[line - 1][0:column])*"-")
```

Note: the `\n` is just for the example you need to split it the right way.